# How do I test if a file does not exist using ZSH?

Tags: zsh, test

This question is about ZSH, not bash.

I have the following lines in my `.zshrc` file.  Whenever I open a terminal I get a `no matches found` error referencing the line with the `if` statement.

```
if [[!( -a ~/.zkbd/$TERM-${${DISPLAY:t}:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE} )]]; then
    zkbd
fi
```

I read through the ZSH documentation and my `if` statement appears to be correct.  I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

What I'd like to happen is for the `zkbd` utility to run if the file in the `.zkbd` folder does not exist.

Comment: @Gilles, how is that a duplicate? OK, in both cases, adding spaces fixes the problem, but considering as duplicates any question where the solution is to add spaces somewhere sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How are they not duplicates? Both are asking why `[ … ]` doesn't work without spaces inside.

Comment: @Gilles, one is about the `[` command, the other one about the `[[...]]` construct, one is about `bash`, the other one is about `zsh`. The error messages are completely different (at least it would make sense to explain why you get a no-match error in zsh here).

Comment: @Gilles, also note that all of `bash`, `ksh93` and `mksh` do support `[[(a == b)]]` (not `[[!(a == b)]]`), not `zsh`.

Comment: don't ask questions you'll get yelled at every time because stackexchange got taken over by "a nicepeoples LONG ago" =~ s/ nicepeop/ssho/g

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to don_crissti for answering this for me.

The correct `if` block is below.

```
if [[ ! -a ~/.zkbd/$TERM-${${DISPLAY:t}:-$VENDOR-$OSTYPE} ]]; then
    zkbd
fi
```

Comment: for ADHD people like me, the solution is [[ -a FILE_NAME ]], the "! -a" asks if the file does not exist.

Comment: @azorius My initial question was asking how to test if a file does not exist.

Comment: can I ask what function this is? How do I search for [[ ... ]] in the manual?

Comment: @Keshav you probably found this, but for anyone still curious, type `man [`